# python web scraping soup.find give empty

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

why a and prices are empty and not extract values from soup even soup has data

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=iphone&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.home.search.go.35e34937c3qzgp')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product

for item in soup.find_all(class_='c3gUW0'):
    prices.append(item.text)

a=soup.find(class_='c3gUW0')
a**strong text**
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore the `requests` module won't support it. However, the data is embedded on the website in JSON format, you can find the data using the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regex) module, and convert it to a Python dictionary (`dict)` using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

For example, to print the name and prices:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=iphone&_keyori=ss&from=input&spm=a2a0e.home.search.go.35e34937c3qzgp"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(re.search(r"window.pageData=({.*})", str(soup)).group(1))
for d in data["mods"]["listItems"]:
    print("Description:", d["name"])
    print("Price:", d["priceShow"])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Output (truncated):

```
Description: Apple iPhone 12 - 64GB - PTA Approved
Price: Rs. 215,000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: iPhone 12 - 128GB - PTA Approved
Price: Rs. 230,000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Description: iPhone 8 Plus - 5.5" Display - 3GB RAM + 64/256GB ROM - Phone Only
Price: Rs. 66,999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```